# How can I change the language of Postgresql logs

Tags: postgresql

Right now my db get disconnected when calling my user function. I would like to ask for help about it but the message are in Spanish.

How I make my logs be in English? I can understand what said, but don't know what to do about it.

Or at least make it show the accent character properly like:

```
terminando la conexiÃ³n
terminando la conexión
```

This is my pg_log file

```
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET LOG:  proceso de servidor (PID 19360) fue terminado por una excepción 0xC0000005
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET DETALLE:  El proceso que falló estaba ejecutando: SELECT * FROM avl_db.process_avl_pool();
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET HINT:  Vea el archivo «ntstatus.h» para una descripción del valor hexadecimal.
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET LOG:  terminando todos los otros procesos de servidor activos
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET WARNING:  terminando la conexiÃ³n debido a una falla en otro proceso servidor
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET DETALLE:  Postmaster ha ordenado que este proceso servidor cancele la transacciÃ³n en curso y finalice la conexiÃ³n, porque otro proceso servidor ha terminado anormalmente y podrÃ­a haber corrompido la memoria compartida.
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET HINT:  Dentro de un momento deberÃ­a poder reconectarse y repetir la consulta.
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET WARNING:  terminando la conexiÃ³n debido a una falla en otro proceso servidor
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET DETALLE:  Postmaster ha ordenado que este proceso servidor cancele la transacciÃ³n en curso y finalice la conexiÃ³n, porque otro proceso servidor ha terminado anormalmente y podrÃ­a haber corrompido la memoria compartida.
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET HINT:  Dentro de un momento deberÃ­a poder reconectarse y repetir la consulta.
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET WARNING:  terminando la conexión debido a una falla en otro proceso servidor
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET DETALLE:  Postmaster ha ordenado que este proceso servidor cancele la transacción en curso y finalice la conexión, porque otro proceso servidor ha terminado anormalmente y podría haber corrompido la memoria compartida.
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET HINT:  Dentro de un momento debería poder reconectarse y repetir la consulta.
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET LOG:  todos los procesos fueron terminados; reinicializando
2016-12-15 17:50:54 VET LOG:  el sistema de bases de datos fue interrumpido; última vez en funcionamiento en 2016-12-15 17:48:02 VET
2016-12-15 17:50:55 VET LOG:  el sistema de bases de datos no fue apagado apropiadamente; se está efectuando la recuperación automática
2016-12-15 17:50:55 VET LOG:  redo comienza en 6/3EBF3360
2016-12-15 17:50:58 VET FATAL:  el sistema de base de datos está en modo de recuperación
2016-12-15 17:50:59 VET LOG:  largo de registro no válido en 6/42B2B628
2016-12-15 17:50:59 VET LOG:  redo listo en 6/42B2B600
2016-12-15 17:50:59 VET LOG:  última transacción completada al tiempo de registro 2016-12-15 17:50:00.246556-04
2016-12-15 17:51:15 VET LOG:  las protecciones de reciclaje de miembros de multixact están habilitadas
2016-12-15 17:51:15 VET LOG:  el sistema de bases de datos está listo para aceptar conexiones
2016-12-15 17:51:15 VET LOG:  lanzador de autovacuum iniciado
```

vacuumdb also give me one error, but also in spanish

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin>vacuumdb.exe -d TrafficEngine -U postgres
vacuumdb: limpiando la base de datos «TrafficEngine»
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 3038 de la relaciÃ³n Â«avlÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 3043 de la relaciÃ³n Â«avlÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 3045 de la relaciÃ³n Â«avlÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 3054 de la relaciÃ³n Â«avlÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 3055 de la relaciÃ³n Â«avlÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 3056 de la relaciÃ³n Â«avlÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 3057 de la relaciÃ³n Â«avlÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 3058 de la relaciÃ³n Â«avlÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 3062 de la relaciÃ³n Â«avlÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 3063 de la relaciÃ³n Â«avlÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 620 de la relaciÃ³n Â«pg_toast_69570Â» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 621 de la relaciÃ³n Â«pg_toast_69570Â» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
WARNING:  la pÃ¡gina 1400 de la relaciÃ³n Â«route_sourcesÂ» no estÃ¡ inicializada --- arreglando
```

---

**`lc_messages`** option: Right now it says `lc_messages = 'Spanish_Spain.1252'`.

What value should I use? I can't find a list of available options.

Comment: Windows is not very good at having several 'locales'. I'd take a look at this [superuser post](http://superuser.com/questions/166089/where-is-the-list-of-available-windows-locales) and [also this one in G-Loaded Journal](https://www.g-loaded.eu/2011/02/27/locale-windows/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you put

```
lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252'
```

into `postgresql.conf` this should work.

You also need to define a [Windows environment variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772047(v=ws.11).aspx) `LC_MESSAGES=English` in order to get `psql` (and the other command line tools) to show English messages.

Comment: `postgresql.conf` did the job with the logs. *now need to wait to fail again*. But the environment variable didnt work. I set it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqkvK.png but doesnt propagate to `Command Window` If I set it by hand `SET lc_messages = English_United States.1252` works ok.

Comment: If you change an environment variable you need to re-start any cmd.exe that is currently running.

Comment: Nevermind, have to close the Setting Window so the changes were save. they should change `'Accept'` button to `'Save'` ;)

Answer (score -1):

For me in postgresql.conf (lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252').

- changed to 'C' - No success

later added to environment variable, it worked.

> $env:LC_MESSAGES='English'
> psql -U postgres
> Password for user postgres: xxxxxx
> English messages